# What Marvel paperback did Toad fight Eel and Wolverine in a Madripoor Tournament?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, x-men, wolverine

Looking for a paperback that contains the Madripoor Tournament where Toad used his tongue to crush Eel's neck and later fought Wolverine. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [Bloodsport](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Bloodsport_(Event)) tournament that took place in *Wolverine* issues 167–169, appearing in 2001.  It was collected in the trade paperback *[Wolverine:  The Return of Weapon X](https://www.marvel.com/comics/collection/47704/wolverine_the_return_of_weapon_x_trade_paperback)*.

Per the Marvel Wikia:

> The Bloodsport was an annual competition in Madripoor. The Bloodsport included a succession of one-on-one fights, each of them ending in the utter defeat of one of the fighters. Use of super-human powers and advanced personal weaponry was allowed, and commonly (but not always) the fight ended in the death of one of the contestants. The winner of the fight would then fight in the following round, until he or she was declared victor.
>
> ...
>
> One of the annual competitions was sponsored and organized by the Viper, with Mister X as previous champion. Under the sight of celebrities in the audience, different super-human fighters gave their blood in the field.

It included Toad killing Eel, but then losing to Wolverine.